# curry is the factorizer for the universal construction

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I am reading category theory for programmers about functions type.

He says:

> Notice that curry is the factorizer for the universal construction of
>   the function object. This is especially apparent if it’s rewritten in
>   this form:
>
> ```
> factorizer :: ((a, b)->c) -> (a->(b->c))
> factorizer g = \a -> (\b -> g (a, b))
> ```
>
> (As a reminder: A factorizer produces the factorizing function from a
>   candidate.)

What is a 'factorizer' and 'universal construction'?

What is he trying to explain about currying?

Comment: can you share where are you reading that please? im interested :)

Comment: Universal construction and factorizers are introduced [here](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/01/07/products-and-coproducts/). [This may be helpful too](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+construction).

Comment: @DanielSanchez https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/

Comment: @n.m. I read about Universal construction but could not figure out what does he mean? Could you please explain it?

Comment: I don't think I can explain it any better than he does. Look at the framed definition "A function object from a to b is an object a⇒b together with the morphism..." etc.

Comment: An Universal construction  is a relation ship between two objects?

Comment: A universal construction in CT is (very roughly) a definition stating someting like "X is an object s.t. for all morphisms ... there is a unique morphism such that ...". Exponentials (function objects) are often defined in that way.

Comment: We say that a morphism `f : a->b` "factorizes" through `c`, if `f = h . g` for some `g : a->c , h : c -> b`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a universal construction and a factorizer was introduced in earlier chapters (in particular in the one about the product and coproduct).

In short, a universal construction compares all possible candidates that share a given property. Here, the candidate is an object `z` with a morphism `g` going from `(z × a)` to `b`. The best such candidate is an object denoted by `(a=>b)` with the morphism called `eval`.

The universal property is that for any candidate `z` together with `g` there is a unique morphism `h` that factorizes the diagram given in the picture. A factorizer is a recipe for obtaining this `h` given `z` and `g`, in a particular category. In Haskell, `g` is a function `((a, z)-> b)` and `h` is a function `(z -> (a -> b))`. So, up to renaming of variables and symmetry of the product, the factorizer has exactly the signature of `curry`.